# VOIP Call Recording in Android

Tags: android, voip, audio-recording

I am trying to record voip call of what's-app and some how able to trigger recording at the same time when an VOIP call is ongoing .

Trying the Below code to record the VOIP Call

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        recorder.prepare();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();
```

but for VOIP call whats app is also using AudioRecorder with the same Audio Source and whoever either my app Recording service or whatsapp able to get an instance of recorder will run perfectly and other app stucked due to Audio Resource Busy . Any suggestion how will i record the Voip Call

Comment: Hi I encountered the same problem, did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: @MittalPatel : Do you have any solution to this?